# ASP.NET UserControl input parameters

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have written my first UserControl like this:

```
public partial class DefectMap : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    const string imageProviderUrl = "~/DefectMapImageProvider.ashx?";

    public long MapID { get; set; }
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public int Cols { get; set; }
    public int? Width { get; set; }
    public int? Height { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComposeImageUrl();
        GenerateTableStructure();
    }

    void ComposeImageUrl()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(imageProviderUrl);
        builder.AppendFormat("DefectMapId={0}", MapID);

        // set up width & height
        if (Width != null && Width > 0)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("&Width={0}", Width);
            MapImage.Width = (Unit)Width;
        }

        if (Height != null && Height > 0)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("&Height={0}", Height);
            MapImage.Height = (Unit)Height;
        }

        MapImage.ImageUrl = builder.ToString();
    }

    void GenerateTableStructure()
    {
        if (Rows > 0 && Cols > 0)
        {
            TableHelper.CreateStructure(MapTable, Rows, Cols);
        }
    }
}
```

If I add this control on some page and set values in markup

```
<uc:DefectMap ID="DefectMap" runat="server" Height="80" MapID="1" />
```

it works like I expect. But if I am trying to set up values (Rows, MapID etc.) in code, it doesn't works. Do you see why not? Should I use different method (than Page_Load) to process controls logic? I use this control as child of GridView, trying this:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DefectMap defectMap = (DefectMap)e.Row.FindControl("DefectMap");
            DEFECTMAP data = (DEFECTMAP)e.Row.DataItem;

            defectMap.MapID = data.ID_DEFECTMAP;
            defectMap.Rows = data.ROWS;
            defectMap.Cols = data.COLS;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Page_Load` is too early - the values are not available.  Either override the `DataBind` method and put the code there (my first choice), or override the `OnPreRender` method and put it there.

Comment: I found similar method as Page_Load: Page_PreRender. Whit it, it works. Thank you.